# How to work withTimeout in Coroutine on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my application I want use `Coroutines` and I write simple code for check `withTimeout` function!
I write below codes, and I think after **3sec** stop my working and show me **Done** message!
But after **3sec** stop coroutines but **not show me** done message!

**My Codes :**

```
CoroutineScope(Default).launch {
    Log.e(TAG, "Start coroutine")
    withTimeout(3000) {
        for (i in 20..50) {
            if (isActive) {
                delay(500)
                Log.e(TAG, "Show i => $i")
            }
        }
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Done coroutine")
}
```

**Logcat messages :**

```
2022-02-05 18:08:11.891 12413-12484/my.app.coroutines E/CoroutinesTag: Start coroutine
2022-02-05 18:08:12.399 12413-12484/my.app.coroutines E/CoroutinesTag: Show i => 20
2022-02-05 18:08:12.900 12413-12485/my.app.coroutines E/CoroutinesTag: Show i => 21
2022-02-05 18:08:13.404 12413-12491/my.app.coroutines E/CoroutinesTag: Show i => 22
2022-02-05 18:08:13.905 12413-12486/my.app.coroutines E/CoroutinesTag: Show i => 23
2022-02-05 18:08:14.406 12413-12491/my.app.coroutines E/CoroutinesTag: Show i => 24
```

Why not show me done (**Done coroutine**) message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

description for `withTimeout`

> Runs a given suspending block of code inside a coroutine with a
> specified timeout timeMillis and throws  a
> TimeoutCancellationException if the timeout was exceeded.

TimeoutCancellationException extends CancellationException which is used for exiting a builder function like `launch` gracefully. If you don't want your job to finish you can use `withTimeoutOrNull`

And from the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#timeout)

> The TimeoutCancellationException that is thrown by withTimeout is a
> subclass of CancellationException. We have not seen its stack trace
> printed on the console before. That is because inside a cancelled
> coroutine CancellationException is considered to be a normal reason
> for coroutine completion. However, in this example we have used
> withTimeout right inside the main function.
>
> Since cancellation is just an exception, all resources are closed in
> the usual way. You can wrap the code with timeout in a try {...} catch
> (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {...} block if you need to do some
> additional action specifically on any kind of timeout or use the
> withTimeoutOrNull function that is similar to withTimeout but returns
> null on timeout instead of throwing an exception:

Comment: Thanks my friend <3 . when add `withTimeoutOrNull` worked to me